# What is the Schar one receives for being amongst the first 10 to a minyan?

Tags: reward-punishment, time, minyan

I know it's important to be amongst the first 10 to a minyan, but what is the reward for doing so?

Comment: Not an easily understood answer, but illustrative (from today's Zohar section of the Chok l'Yisrael) https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1413564/jewish/Daily-Zohar-Teruma-Day-1.htm